# Outer Apparent Horizon is a Null Hypersurface

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, causality

Let $(N,h)$ be a 4 dimensional spacetime, $M$ be some spacelike hypersurface in $N$ and $S$ be some closed hypersurface in $M$. Let $K$ be some null normal field on $S$. This is the standard set up for defining an outer apparent horizon, which will be $S$.

I believe that one of the conditions for $S$ being an outer apparent horizon in the spacetime $N$ is that $S$ must be a null hypersurface. Thus, this must mean that $S$ is a null hypersurface in $M$ and so the normal field $K \in  \Gamma(TS)^{\perp} \subset \Gamma(TM) $ must be null. But $M$ is spacelike so any of its tangent vectors have positive inner product. Thus for $p \in S$, $K(p) \in {(TpS)}^{\perp} \subset TpM$ cannot be null.

This is an unwanted contradiction and I'm wondering where my logic is flawed.

Comment: why does $S$ have to be a subset of $M$? The apparent horizon relative to the spacelike leaf M will be the spacelike 2-surface formed by the intersection of $S$ and $M$, right?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: Apologies, I appeared to have made a typo in a crucial place. I mean to say that $S$ is a closed hypersurface in $M$.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: You say the apparent horizon will be spacelike. I'm under the impression that the outer apparent horizon must be a null surface, not a spacelike surface. Perhaps my understanding is incorrect and then there is no issue here?

Comment: The outer horizon is a null surface spanned by one null vector and two spacelike vectors.  In a static spacetime, the apparent horizon will be a spacelike submanifold of that null surfice.

Comment: I suppose my issue with this is that if it is spanned by one null vector then this null vector must be in the tangent space of $M$ also, right? But if $M$ is spacelike then it can't have any null vectors in its tangent space at any point?

Comment: Yes, everything you said is right.  M is a two dimensional space, but the event horizon is a three dimensional space.  The null direction is in the normal direction of M relative to S.

Comment: Also, be super careful when doing intrinsic geometry on null surfaces.  the metric is non-invertible, so raising and lowering indices no longer works.

Comment: I appreciate the comment once more, thank you. However I still don't understand. I'm using $M$ to be a "spacelike slice" of our spacetime $N$. So $M$ will be three dimensional. $S$ is then a (closed) hypersurface in $M$ so is 2-dimensional. Is the horizon (by Hawking) not topologically ${\mathcal{S}^2}$, so must be 2 dimensional - not 3 dimensional? By horizon I mean apparent horizon, not event horizon.

Comment: The apparent horizon is two dimensional, yes. it is the "horizon" (probably "trapped surface" is a more accurate term) as viewed from a particular spacelike foliation.

Comment: Note that in fully dynamical cases, stacks of apparent horizons (or trapped surfaces) do not necessarily even have to be null surfaces or correspond to the event horizon at all.

Comment: as in, because the above definition depends on a spacelike foliation, the apparent horizon is *not* geometrically invariant.